# Running cmd.exe with arguments from c#

Tags: c#

I have folder C:\Temp\ which has two file des.exe and input.abcd. des.exe is used to decrypt input.abcd. below 2 lined works in command prompt

```
cd C:\Temp\
des.exe XXXX input.abcd output.zip
```

why below does not work from c#

```
        string argument1 =  "/K cd C:\\Temp\\ ";
        string argument2 = "des.exe XXXX input.abcd output.zip" ;
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new      System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        proc.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", argument1, argument2);
        proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;            
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```

Comment: no error but i don't see output.zip means it is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to run cmd.exe as a process. All you need to do is run "c:\temp\des.exe" with the arguments of "XXXX input.abcd output.zip".

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp\des.exe", "XXXX input.abcd output.zip");
```

Be sure to give your arguments the correct full-paths as well if they are different from the temp dir.

Comment: Try `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\temp\des.exe", " XXXX c:\temp\input.abcd c:\temp\output.zip");`.

Answer (score 0):

The process you want to run is dec.exe, not cmd.exe.  Try this, substitute {fullPath} with path to des.exe:

```
     string argument2 = "XXXX input.abcd output.zip";
     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
     proc.FileName = @"C:\\Temp\\des.exe";
     proc.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}",  argument2);
     proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```